# Magento Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on a non-object

Tags: php, magento, model

I am attempting to override a model in a third party extension so I can add a few more columns to the database table it uses and manipulate them. I've added the following in `config.xml`:

```
<marketplace>
     <rewrite>
         <userprofile>ZeroBars_Marketplacepayment_Model_Userprofile</userprofile>
     </rewrite>
</marketplace>
```

and copied the `Userprofile.php` file into my module's Model folder. The code in Userprofile makes a call to the collection of the previous Model that I am overriding:

```
public function getPartnerProfileById($partnerId) {
        $data = array();
        if ($partnerId != '') {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$partnerId));

...
```

and I am now served with a `Fatal Error` for calling `addFieldToFilter`. I've tried copying over the files in Mysql4 as well but I am not sure how to go about adding an override for them in config. How can I sleuth out what is going wrong?

Comment: `$collection` is empty that is why it shows that error. To dig out your problem please provide your modules `config.xml`, extension's `config.xml` and its model file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KRay, for get collection of table then you need Define Collection for that model

I you need to class collection file of that module which is  fetch all data of the table

Collection file path is Collection.php app/code/yourcodePOol/your pakkage name/Modulename/Model/Resource/Userprofile/

```
<?php
class YourPackagename_Modulename_Model_Resource_Userprofile_Collection
extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract{
    protected function _constuct(){
        $this->_init('marketplace/userprofile');    
    }
}
```

If you using mysql4 as resource model then try

```
   <?php
    class YourPackagename_Modulename_Model_Mysql4_Userprofile_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
    {
        public function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('marketplace/userprofile');
        }
    }
```

- See more at: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/